# how to redirect www subdomain to non-www when domain is redirected to www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, no-www

My primary domain is currently permanently redirected to **www.mydomain.com** (non-www to www redirection), with .htaccess as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.mydomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mydomain.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mydomain.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mydomain.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mydomain.com$      [NC]
```

I would like to know how all subdomains that I'll be creating, ex. blog.mydomain.com, will be redirected to non-www, ex. **blog.mydomain.com**, and *not* **www.blog.mydomain.com**. Every time I create a subdomain and enter the non-www URL to the browser, it prompts a redirect loop.

Hope you can help! Thanks! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htaccess add www if not subdomain, if subdomain remove www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285074/htaccess-add-www-if-not-subdomain-if-subdomain-remove-www)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Keep this one rule for all the sub-domains:

```
# rule for forcing www on main domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# rule for removing www on sub domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Can we make http part dynamic so that if site changes to https then it should be automatic?

Comment: This is not working if anyone adds `https://` before `www.sub.domain.com`

Comment: It is definitely a working rule and it has nothing to do with `https`

Comment: Suppose I have my subdomain xyz.abc.com and now if someone browse to www.xyz.abc.com then it perfectly redirects to xyz.abc.com but if anyone adds https:// infront of www.xyz.abc.com then it is not able to redirect to without www

Comment: @MrinmoyMk: Can you post a new question for this and I will post an answer there.

Comment: this works fine for main domain and it redirect `mydomain.com` to `https://www.` as I want but it doesn't redirect `sub.mydomain.com` to `https://sub.`

Comment: @Cem: This answer is not for `http -> https`. This is for removal of `www` for subdomains and adding `www` for main domain.

Answer (score 3):

This one supports `http` + `https` in one line:

```
# Redirect www subdomain to non-www 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.yourdomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```