# htaccess vs virtualhost - Caret match ^

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I've been coming up with some redirects for a client, where they needed a redirect on domain.com to have leading www, and a sub.another.com that has been aliased to domain.com to not have leading www. I've found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21986058/9343705), which kinda-worked.

My senior told me, that the caret-only match (e.g. the `RewriteRule ^` part) does not work in .htaccess, apparently only in virtualhost. I know that there are some minor differences between these, but I was unable to find any source (and he wasn't able to provide it too) that says that `^` match doesn't work in .htaccess.

Apparently, the correct rule would be `RewriteRule ^(.*) https://sub.another.com/$1 [R=301,L]`. Can anyone please explain why the match doesn't work in .htaccess? If the internet is to be believed, both `^` and `^(.*)` should match the entire line. The latter explicitly tells to match anything after beginning of the line, while the former matches the beginning of the line itself (so should also match an empty string, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41407273/9343705)).

Comment: Of course using `^` works in .htaccess as well - but you need to pay attention to what you are trying to match after that. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule, section titled "What is matched?", explains the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My senior told me, that the caret-only match (e.g. the `RewriteRule ^` part) does not work in `.htaccess`, apparently only in virtualhost

That is nonsense. The `^` (regex syntax) simply asserts the start-of-string. Nothing more. So, if an argument takes a regex (regardless of context) the `^` is always going to "work", depending on what you are trying to match. (I'm wondering whether you really mean the slash prefix on the URL-path?)

> apparently only in virtualhost

You could argue the opposite is true. `^$` will match in `.htaccess`, but not in a virtualhost context. (This matches the root directory / homepage in a `.htaccess` context.)

This is simply due to what is matched in these different *contexts*. (There are 4 contexts in the Apache config: `.htaccess`, *directory*, *virtualhost* and *server*.)

In a *virtualhost* context, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the full root-relative URL-path, starting with a slash. So, instead of `^$`, you would need to match `^/$` instead (to match the root directory).

Whereas in `.htaccess` (and *directory*) context, the URL-path that is matched is relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file (the directory-prefix has been removed) and consequently does **not** start with a slash.

For example, given the URL `https://example.com/foo/bar/baz`...

- In a virtualhost context, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path `/foo/bar/baz` (the full URL-path starting with a slash.)
- In `.htaccess` in the root directory then the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against `foo/bar/baz` (no slash prefix). But if the `.htaccess` file is located in the `/foo` subdirectory (not the root) then the URL-path that is matched is: `bar/baz` only (`/foo` is omitted).

> Apparently, the correct rule would be `RewriteRule ^(.*) https://sub.another.com/$1 [R=301,L]`. Can anyone please explain why the match doesn't work in `.htaccess`?

This **does** work in `.htaccess`. In fact, this would only work properly in `.htaccess`, since if you used this rule in a *virtualhost* context then you would end up with a double-slash at the start of the URL-path in the redirected request. (Of course, other rules can affect this behaviour and the location of the `.htaccess` file - if in a subdirectory - will change this behaviour also.)

> If the internet is to be believed, both `^` and `^(.*)` should match the entire line.

`^` by itself does not *match* anything, it simply asserts the start-of-string, so is always "successful". Whereas `^(.*)` asserts the start-of-string and then matches the rest of the URL-path and captures this in a backreference. In fact, the `^` prefix in `^(.*)` is entirely optional (when matching URL-paths) since the regex is *greedy*. `^(.*)` and `(.*)` are "the same".

Since you are using a `$1` backreference in the *substitution* string you need to actually capture something, so you need `(.*)` (since `^` does not match/capture anything, it's simply an *assertion*). But this is the same, regardless of where you are using this directive: `.htaccess` or *virtualhost*.

In this particular rule, you could use `^` only and use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable in the *substitution* string instead. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://sub.another.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Note that the `REQUEST_URI` variable contains the entire URL-path, including the slash prefix, so the slash is omitted in the *substitution* string. This rule is arguably "better" than using the backreference (your rule above) since it works *anywhere* (any directory), regardless of context and uses a more efficient regex.

Comment: What an exhaustive answer, thank you very much. I was aware that there are context differences between vhosts and htaccess/directory, but I guess I haven't paid much attention while reading the docs. Your explanatory of the regex part is especially awesome